# How to implement flip effect in page navigation in winrt?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have tiles on my home screen. i want when user click any tile then next page should open up with the animation same like in start screen. when user click any tile on start screen it flips and open up.

Answer (score 0):

It might be hard to implement with the basic Frame control implementation, since it only has one content, so you would need to flip the tile halfway, fade out the rest of the page and then immediately load and flip the next page. It would be more doable if you could load your next page in some transparent container before you animate it in.

You can do the transforms used to flip controls by animating the rotation property of the PlaneProjection object assigned to the UI element's Projection property.

Also note that the start screen only needs to load and animate the small splash screen image of the started application. If your next page requires any loading you might need to preload it before the navigation is invoked to avoid the delay before the smooth navigation can start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web application, I would suggest you to go with JQuery.

You will find lots of plugin out there.